# Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic) in Windows command prompt

Tags: linux, ssh, fedora, openssh

I'm not able to SSH into the Fedora VM hosted in google cloud, from windows command prompt. I have tried to search for the answer in web but I couldn't find any explanation/solution given for windows specifically.

I have performed below steps:

1. Created a VM in google cloud with below image

`fedora-cloud-base-gcp-34-1-2-x86-64`

2. Allowed access to VM via port 22 in the firewall.
3. In windows command prompt ran below command to generate public and private key:

   ssh-keygen -t ecdsa
4. Added the public key to VM.

Now when I run **ssh username@host** in command prompt from .ssh folder, I get below error:

```
PS C:\Users\user1\.ssh> ssh -i C:/Users/user1/.ssh/id_ecdsa user1@34.19.24.7
The authenticity of host '34.19.24.7 (34.19.24.7)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:3/NMD26H/bhz9DJYHssTcFAKEpttgpobGac.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])? yes
Warning: Permanently added '34.19.24.7' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
user1@34.19.24.7: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
```

Funny thins is I'm able to connect to other VM under same subnetwork which is created using "Debian" image.

**What is causing this failure and how can I fix this ?**

PFB the debug logs for this command:

```
PS C:\Users\user1\.ssh> ssh -v -i C:/Users/user1/.ssh/id_ecdsa user1@34.19.24.7
OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1p1, LibreSSL 3.0.2
debug1: Connecting to 34.19.24.7 [34.19.24.7] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file C:/Users/user1/.ssh/id_ecdsa type 2
debug1: identity file C:/Users/user1/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_8.5
debug1: match: OpenSSH_8.5 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to 34.19.24.7:22 as 'user1'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:3/NMD26H/bhz9DJYHssTcFAKEpttgpobGac
debug1: Host '34.19.24.7' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in C:\\Users\\user1/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: pubkey_prepare: ssh_get_authentication_socket: No such file or directory
debug1: Will attempt key: C:/Users/user1/.ssh/id_ecdsa ECDSA SHA256:nGbnvW+SfJQfakeHcpXzw+8nJbtnqQWPNQtro+q/8 explicit
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,webauthn-sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: C:/Users/user1/.ssh/id_ecdsa ECDSA SHA256:nGbnvW+SfJQU9fakepXzw+8nJbtnqQWPNQtro+q/8 explicit
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
```